# What is the correct definition of the blowfish F-function?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, blowfish

The [Blowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) cipher uses a so called `F`-function which uses [S-Boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box) (`S[i]`, `i=0,1,2,3`) to chiffre an integer `x`, for which I've seen different versions:

1. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29):

   ```
   uint32_t F (uint32_t x) {
       uint32_t h = S[0][x >> 24] + S[1][x >> 16 & 0xff];
       return ( h ^ S[2][x >> 8 & 0xff] ) + S[3][x & 0xff];
   }
   ```
2. [source](http://www.herongyang.com/Blowfish/Algorithm-Blowfish-Cipher-Encryption-Algorithm.html):

   ```
   uint32_t F (uint32_t x) {
       uint32_t h = S[0][x >> 24] + S[1][x >> 16 & 0xff] % (2**32);
       return ( h ^ S[2][x >> 8 & 0xff] ) + S[3][x & 0xff] % (2**32);
   }
   ```

`F` should output a 32 bit value. The second version tries to handle overflows - although I dont see how this works when the values in the S-Boxes itself are 32 bit.

I realize this also depends on the language in which the cipher is implemented.

If we're assuming to implement it in `C`, the high bytes in case of an overflow in `S[0][x >> 24] + S[1][x >> 16 & 0xff]` would just be cut off.

Is this just the way it should work for the `F`-function?

Comment: $\mod {2^{32}}$ should be expected for uint32 values, I don't see any reason why `% (2**32)` would do anything at all.

Comment: It seems to me that you've misinterpreted the pseudocode [here](http://www.herongyang.com/Blowfish/Algorithm-Blowfish-Cipher-Encryption-Algorithm.html) while translating it to C: the code is clearly using `x + y mod 2**32` to mean "add `x` and `y` modulo `2**32`", or, in other words, "add `x` and `y` using 32-bit integer arithmetic" -- *not* "reduce `y` modulo `2**32` and add the result to `x`" like your C code reads.

Comment: Well, thanks, that explains that part. Overflows in 32-bit integer arithmetic will occur, though - that's just how it works for the blowfish algorithm?

Comment: To be exact: the expression `expr1 + expr2` in C where both expr1 and expr2 are 32-bits is *not* guaranteed to "cut off ... high bytes"; it's entirely legal (though currently rare) for `int` to be wider than (and rank above) 32 bits. What is guaranteed is *assigning or returning* to `uint32_t` (assuming the standard-specified type not a user-made-up one); those do force modulo for a narrower unsigned integer -- but not signed. This is one of the reasons C is not as good for bitbashing crypto pseudocode as some believe.